# Inkscape difference with multiple objects selected

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to cut multiple holes in a rectangle but it doesn't work.  The steps I take are:

1. create rectangle
2. create multiple circles on top of it
3. selects circles then rectangle, go to Path tab, then click difference

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only use the Difference operation on two objects at a time, but there is a way to work around that.

Make the circles into a compound path first. Select them all and click *Path > Combine.*  Now select both rectangle and combined circles, then click *Path > Difference*

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between Combine and Union?

Comment: @Lai32290 - in some cases Union and Combine can both produce combined paths, if the paths are not overlapping, however Union will create one path if the paths overlap.  Try both, and you'll see!